# string.format equivalence in java

Tags: c#, java

What is the equivalent Java implementation for [string.format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx)?

```
string s = string.Format("{0} - ({1})", myparam1, myparam2);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
String formatted = String.format("%s - (%s)", myparam1, myparam2);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was interested in the Message format string %s - (%s)

Answer (score 3):

Err... [String.format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) seems like a pretty good candidate. Who would have thought? :-)

There is also [MessageFormat.format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer is correct. I would just like to add the Java equivalent of *argument index* like OP has used in his post. Please, note that I have reversed the argument positions but they would still print in order.

```
String fmtStr = String.format("%2$s - (%1$s)", myparam2, myparam1);
```

Format-string argument indices start from `1` in Java.

Answer (score 1):

in Java, String.format patterns are different like %s or %1$d etc.
if you are looking for dotnet similarity it is Messageformat.format